# Laravel storing only last image

Tags: laravel, axios, nuxt.js

i'm trying to upload and store multiple images, but only the last image is being saved, the rest are just ignored.

I'm using Nuxt,Axios and Laravel as an API.

[This is the FormData Console.log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N0Fi7.png)

[And this is the Laravel API response with only the last image added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/upr6p.png)

Hope someone can help me to figure out what's going on, thanks in advance

```
Pug 

input(type='file' ref='files' accept='image/*' multiple @change='handleFilesUpload()' style='display:none')
.text-xs-right.pb-3
    v-btn(@click='$refs.files.click()' color='#B6944C')
       v-icon add

    v-btn(color='green' @click='submitFiles()')
```

```
Axios

async submitFiles(){
       let fd = new FormData()
       for(var i = 0; i < this.files.length; i++){
         let file = this.files[i]
         //fd.append('photo[' + i + ']', file)
         fd.append('photo[]', file)
       }
       try{
        await this.$axios.$post(`/albums/${this.$route.params.id}/photos`, fd, {headers:{'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'}})
        console.log(...fd)
        alert('uploaded')
        this.files = ''
        //this.$router.push(`/photo/${this.$route.params.id}`)
        //location.reload()
      }
      catch(err){
        console.log(err.response.data)
        alert(err)
      }

     }
```

```
Laravel Controller 

public function store(PhotoInAlbumRequest $request, Album $album){
        $photo = new PhotoInAlbum();
        $photo->photo = $request->photo;

        $images = $request->file('photo');
        if($request->hasfile('photo')){
            foreach($images as $image){
                $filenameWithExt = $image->getClientOriginalName();
                $filename = pathInfo($filenameWithExt, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
                $extension = $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
                $filenameToStore = $filename.'_'.time().'.'.$extension;
                $path = $image->storeAs('photo/images',$filenameToStore,'public');
                $photo->photo = $path;
                $album->photos()->save($photo);
            }
        }
        return new PIAResource($photo);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it moving this 2 lines, inside the Foreach, now it's working (=

```
$photo = new PhotoInAlbum();
$photo->photo = $request->photo;
```